# Explaining the apostrophe in this quotation

Tags: grammar, possessives, apostrophe

Stumbled upon [The Case For Mitt Romney](http://andrewsullivan.thedailybeast.com/2012/11/case-romney.html):

> So far, under Obama, private sector job growth has vastly outpaced the public sector. And the big public unions, like the **teachers'**, have been directly challenged.

I couldn't wrap my head around the *apostrophe* used after *teachers*— marked in bold. So, is there anything implied that I don't see or is this a type of apostrophe that I am not aware of?

Comment: It's possessive. The union belongs to the teachers. If a bunch of engineers  own a blue car, you can say "... the blue cars, like the engineers', ...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These examples show the various distinct possibilities, and should clarify what is going on.

- Whose car is that? It belongs to them.  It’s their car. It’s theirs.
- Whose car is that? It belongs to our teacher.  It’s our teacher’s car. It’s our teacher’s.
- Whose lounge is that? It belongs to those teachers. It’s those teachers’ lounge.   It’s those teachers’.

Answer (score 2):

Plural nouns that end in "s" usually only get the apostrophe instead of apostrophe + "s".  (Apostrophe + "s" are used for singular possesive nouns that do not end in "s", such as as "dog's" tail.)  Plural nouns that do not end in "s" get the apostrophe + "s" as in "men's" and "children's".

These rules are explained very well on this site:

http://www.meredith.edu/grammar/plural.htm

Answer (score 1):

> public unions, like the teachers'

This refers to the *public unions of the teachers*.

*Teachers* is plural; under the usual rules, the normal possessive form would be *teachers's* — which contracts to omit the second *s*.

This is a common contraction for possessive plurals.

Comment: You need to be very careful about saying the "normal" form is *teachers's* and that's contracted to *teachers'*, because contractions can be expanded without damage. **Teachers's* is wrong and not normal.

Comment: I did say *would be* not *is*. But is that better?

Comment: The contraction you describe happened in Middle English, and -- because it can no longer be expanded and remain correct -- can't be thought of as a contraction *now*. It's now the normative form and to describe the pre-Middle English form as "usual" and "normal" isn't right. Better to get rid of the last two paragraphs altogether.